# How do I include the Decimal struct in the anchor idl?

Tags: anchor, anchor-program-idl, math

I have copied the math section from the token lending program here

https://github.com/solana-labs/solana-program-library/tree/master/token-lending/program/src/math

Decimal struct is as below

```
// U192 with 192 bits consisting of 3 x 64-bit words
construct_uint! {
    pub struct U192(3);
}

/// Large decimal values, precise to 18 digits
#[derive(Clone, Copy, Debug, Default, PartialEq, PartialOrd, Eq, Ord)]
pub struct Decimal(pub U192);
```

If I use this in an account struct then Decimal is not included in the idl

```
#[account(zero_copy)]
#[derive(Default)]
pub struct MyState {
   pub bump: u8,
   pub calculation: Decimal,
}
```

Gives the following error when I test

```
IdlError: Type not found: {"name":"calculation","type":{"defined":"Decimal"}}
```

Should I be using a different math library with anchor?

Comment: Have you copied it into your `lib.rs` or as its own module file?

Comment: I have copied the enire math folder into my workspace

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to re-import the `math` module into your `lib.rs`, i.e.

```
use crate::math::*;
```

Anchor macros assume (probably short-sightedly) that all the structs and types referenced in accounts and instruction data are available in the current module.

The above `use` makes re-imports those straight into the root module and visible to the macros without being qualified.